# Constructor in custom controller?

Tags: plugin-development, controller

I'm implementing a custom controller as part of a plugin I'm building. There's some set up work that I'd like to do in the controller's constructor. I created a `__construct` method, and it seems to work as expected.

**My question:** Is there some reason that I should call `parent::__construct()` inside of the constructor? It requires an argument, which looks like it should be an ID of some sort, but I'm not sure where I should get that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a huge fan of it but for this situation it might be more appropriate to use `init()`, Looking at `Craft\BaseController`:

```
/**
 * Initializes the controller.  This method is called by the Craft before the controller starts to execute.
 *
 * @throws HttpException
 * @return null
 */
public function init()
{

}
```

It seems a little odd to me to have a constructor for a controller though, what is it you're doing in it? [Yii's Controller filters](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter) might be a better fit.

Comment: +1 for using `init()` here.

Comment: This sounds great. I was using __construct just because it's what I'm used to doing when extending a class. In many other languages or frameworks, it's required. I didn't know if the same was true here. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

\Craft\BaseController extends \CController so if you want to have a custom constructor, you should accept the same parameters and call the parent constructor with them.

```
/**
 * @param string $id id of this controller
 * @param CWebModule $module the module that this controller belongs to.
 */
public function __construct($id, $module = null)
{
    parent::__construct($id, $module);
}
```

Comment: Thanks coffe4u. I saw this as well, but I didn't know how to get the $id for my controller as I was constructing it, and I didn't know what I was supposed to pass back as the $module. I think the correct answer is to not use a constructor, but the init() method as suggested above. It's Brad Bell approved, which makes me feel pretty good about it :)